# Is there any vocal aggression in the Quran?

Tags: quran-recitation, tajweed

I am wondering whether the tone in the Quran is ever vocally aggressive and whether reciters are supposed to mimic it. Be it disturbed by certain matters or due to disappointment in the transgressors.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar has been mentioned.  There are several reports describing the Prophets tone of recitation as going along with what was being recited.  And this is actually also part of tajwid.

In Sahih Muslim, the companion Hudhaifa said that one night he prayed with Rasulullah...**And when he recited the verses which referred to the Glory of Allah, he glorified (Allah), and when he recited the verses which tell (how the Lord) is to be begged, he (Prophet) would then beg (Allah), and when he recited the verses dealing with protection from the Lord, he sought (His) protection...**

So the Prophet acted out what was being recited.  Not sure if that's what you're asking.

AllahoAlim